# Reading numbers without spaces from a text file (java)

Tags: java, io

if we have a text file with the numbers arranged without spaces as follows:

```
1223443
1239866
```

how can each digit be read individually? since we can no longer use the hasNextInt() function.

Comment: Read the whole line, parse every character?

Comment: should this be done with string tokenizer then typcasted?

Comment: I mean you could just go through the array produced by the String (toCharArray()) and just get an int by subtracting  the character'0' from each character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this. For example, read in a single line from the file, then store in in some String s. Then, you can do something simple like use the `split()` function.

```
String s = "1223443 1239866";
String[] numberStrings = s.split(" ");
for (String num : numberStrings)
{
    int value = Integer.parseInt(num);
}
```

I suggest you read up on the [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. It is very commonly used when parsing Strings.

To read each digit individually...

```
String s = "1234";
for (char c : s.toCharArray())
{
    int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Comment: @EternalPunishment Editted my answer to accomodate this change.

Comment: I feel that using two method calls is a bit overkill when you can just easily subtract '0' from the character's value

Comment: @kirbyquerby In my opinion, subtracting character values is much less readable. Using parseInt is also better because it will throw a RuntimeException if a non-numeric value is found, whereas the '0' approach will yield a strange result.

Comment: @kon i'm a bit confused about how the values are stored. do they get stored in a one dimension array? can i store them in a two dimension array?

Comment: @Kon You bring up a point with the RuntimeException, but I personally think that in a perfect world with perfect data sets, using subtraction is acceptable(as long as you use the literal, not the integer value) and readable.

Comment: @EternalPunishment Internally, a String is backed by an array of characters (since that's just all that a String is). It is a one dimensional array because any String only has a length. There is no concept of another dimension. You should read the file line by line, assigned one line to one String, then parsing as shown above.

Comment: @kirbyquerby It depends, I suppose. Arguments can be made both ways. In production code I usually see preference for the approach I've shown; literals in the code anywhere are usually somewhat frowned upon. The whole "magic number" thing is overblown but it can be a harbinger of messy code.